# button text wrapping in Angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

**Objective**: I have a long text stored in a variable that I need to display as a text in a button. Since it is a long text, I wish to wrap it.
**Example**:
say the variable is `$scope.buttonText`, containg a long text(say 100 characters).
The button code (angular material is used) in the view is:

```
<md-button ng-click="someFunc()" style="width:300px;">
{{buttonText}}
</md-button>
```

The **Expected Output** is that the text in the button should wrap after 300px.
But the **actual output** of the above code is that the text is not wrapping after 300px. It just goes on and breaks the button. The spilled out text gets hidden.
Now, I have tried using the some CSS properties on it like `white-space: normal;` but it does not seem t work on the text at all.
I assume this is because the text is actually as a `$scope` variable.
Can someone help me in wrapping up the text in the button, which has a fixed width of `300px`? Height is no issue.
A [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/EgjqwiaE2sepVgiHZjMS?p=preview) to regenerate the problem. please someone suggest changes.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.appText {
    width: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button style="width:300px;">
<span class="appText">sssssssssssssssssssxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxsssssssssssssssss</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This CSS is not working... The text is still not wrapping :(

Comment: please add `display: inline-block;` to appText class

Comment: still not working... i have made a plunkr... plz edit it : [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EgjqwiaE2sepVgiHZjMS?p=preview)

Comment: @jAYANT YADAV you need to add the 'appText' css class to html.  replace button tag with this    `<button>
        <span class="appText">{{buttonText}} </span>
      </button>`

Comment: sorry. I thought i had included it... But the text is still not wrapping... I have removed the `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` since i want to see the whole text in button

Comment: but if the text is more than 300px long it should wrapped right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134389/discussion-between-jayant-yadav-and-sachila-ranawaka).